# Warning: Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small) with lint

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, lint

```
long keyIntValue;
uint8_t *value; 

*(long *)value = keyIntValue;
```

I get Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small) while linting. 
Help me to understand why I get it and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a "pointer to uint8_t" (`uint8_t *`) to a `long *`. As for a uint8_t only one byte (assuming 8 bits) is available, any assgnment to the now `long *` would overflow to the following bytes (a `long` has at least 32 bits = 4 bytes) which do not belong to the object pointed to, thus creating undefined behaviour (UB).

Note that as shown, `value` is undefined at the time of the assignment, exhibiting also UB.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, our code exhibits [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you're dereferencing unitialized pointer `value`.

That said, a `uint8_t` is *too short* to hold a value of type `long`. You should better know what you're doing.

Rule-of-thumb: Don't try to cast *pointers*, they can create alignment issues. (If you have to) Cast *values* instead.

Comment: You are right, but none of them is a pointer-pointer conversion.

Comment: @Olaf and what exactly do you mean by a `pointer-pointer conversion`?

Comment: That's what was reported by lint according to the question. For a pointer-to-pointer conversion, it would reqire one pointer to be smaller than the other (here: the receiving pointer). That might be true for some embedded systems. But not for the data types (that should generate a truncation warning/error). uin8_t and long are no pointers.

Comment: @Olaf You're very right. I stopped digging after seeing UB. There must be something else. Thanks for noting and the comment. :-)

Comment: Welcome. After a bit thinking, you might be right actually for the line of the message, but not for the cause (not sure if the OP cut some code in-between where `value` is actually initialized). But the text is a bit missleading. It might mean the cast between the pointers is unsafe such as any assignment to the resulting `long *` will exhibit UB (`uint8_t *` converted to `long *`). I'll answer myself

Comment: @Olaf agree. Missed this point of view, too. [_it shows, Friday is here_]

Comment: :-) I's appreciate if you have a look at my answer, too.